# div element not including the padding of span children

Tags: css

Please see what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/78UuQ/

The padding overflows outside of the div border. How can I get it inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The span's `display` property must be set to `inline-block` in order for height's to make a difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/46Gvk/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/78UuQ/5/

The span is `inline` element and doesn't preserve margin. You have to make it block and float it.

Comment: Making it a block and floating it is the same thing as making it "display: inline-block"

Comment: Yes, minus the browser support, that is.

Comment: `float:left` forces `display:block`, so there is no need to state it separately. Just `float:left` will do.